# How do I define a generic (polymorphic) function in Rascal?

Tags: rascal

I would like to define a generic function to extract keys from a map, something like this:

```
public list[K] keys(map[K,V] aMap) {
    return [ key | key:val <- aMap ];
}
```

Although no syntax error is given, this does not work. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define this as

```
public list[&K] keys(map[&K,&V] aMap) {
    return [ k | k <- aMap ];
}
```

Note that the keys are unordered, so it may make more sense to return them as a set instead of as a list. You can also always get the keys or values out as sets directly by projecting them out of the map, using either

```
aMap<0>
```

for the set of keys or

```
aMap<1>
```

for the set of values. Finally, the Set module contains a toList function, so you could do this in one line as

```
toList(aMap<0>)
```

which will give you the same result as calling the keys function.

Comment: and if the map has names, then you can project using the names as in `map[&K keys, &V values] x = ...; x<keys>;` or `x<values>`.